# Will custom sequence generator cause 'Too many objects match the primary key'

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using the following method to generate a sequence for my ADF 12c application..

```
     protected void doDML(int operation, TransactionEvent e) {
            if (operation == DML_INSERT) {
                SequenceImpl seq = new SequenceImpl("PATIENT_ID_SEQ", getDBTransaction());
                setPatientId(seq.getSequenceNumber().longValue());
            }
            super.doDML(operation, e);
        }
```

I am at times getting
Too many objects match the primary key oracle.jbo.Key[-1 ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating the PK attribute in doDML happens 'too late'.  You need a primary key as soon as you create the row in ADF (the moment you press ADD button)

You will need this approach:
https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/using-groovy-expression-to-set-a-primary-key-with-a-sequence-number/

Comment: Thanks Marcus.. you saved my day.. again!!